# Jasperserver 6.3.0 (Tomcat 8.0.14) startup.bat: Unrecognized option: --JvmMs

Tags: java-8, tomcat8, jasperserver

As mentioned in the question:
Why can't I start it out of my `tomcat\bin` dir?

```
> apache-tomcat\bin\startup.bat
Unrecognized option: --JvmMs

> java -version
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

(It works running it as a service though, there it's started differently: `C:\JASPER~1\JASPER~1.0\APACHE~1\bin\tomcat8.exe //RS//jasperreportsTomcat`)
(I did not set it up though)

Answer (score 0):

Outcommenting (via `rem`) the following line in **`apache-tomcat\bin\setenv.bat`** did the job:

```
rem set JAVA_OPTS= --JvmMs 1024 --JvmMx 2048 --JvmSs 2 %JAVA_OPTS%
```

Since I use it as a test instance, I don't care about the JVM memory settings too much here, but maybe somebody knows the cause and a more appropriate solution?